# model is not defined in ajax call response in mvc

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I am sending model and checkbox value data to the controller from the view. While at run time it showing me error i.e. **model is not defined**. This error is showing me when I call the ajax in mvc view.

Here is my code,

```
@model VendorModel
<input type="checkbox" id="chb_wholesale" onclick="WholeSaleCheck()" />@T("WholeSale")
<script>
    function WholeSaleCheck() {
        alert(Model.vendorId);
    }
</script>
```

Now, I am surprised that why showing me this type of error because Model also available and after tying the Model word showing list of their property field also one of the field is vendorId and that also automatically**(by pressing ctrl+space)**.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, by coding this **@Model.vendorId** error is solve out.